# ClassNotFoundException when running Java with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I recently started learning how to use Gradle and am having an issue of a ClassNotFoundException when trying to run a server. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this. I have no problems running the server or client in the command line, so I'm not sure why Gradle's giving me so much trouble.

Am I just misunderstanding how Gradle's classpath declaration works? After looking online, I thought it might be because my code wasn't directly in a src/main folder, so I moved both files to one, but I'm still getting the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the classpath:

```
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
main = 'ser321-spring2021-A-amarce1.Assignment3.tcp.src.main.Server'
```

And my GitHub/command line path is as follows:

```
ser321-spring2021-A-amarce1/Assignment3/tcp/src/main/Server.java
```

Answer (score 0):

The class path starts inside the source set, i.e. *after* `/src/main/…`. Your class `Server` is located in the default package. I assume it does not have a `package com.example;` as first line.

You need to move it to the correct package:

```
…/src/main/ser321-spring2021-A-amarce1/Assignment3/tcp/Server.java
```

and add the corresponding package declaration:

```
package ser321-spring2021-A-amarce1.Assignment3.tcp;
```